# Why does this diode appear to show a phantom voltage?

Tags: voltage, diodes, phantom

There is a back story to this, but I'll skip that for the moment and get to the point.
I built a circuit to control remote lights using XBee devices and a PIC microcontroller and was diagnosing an issue (an unexpected voltage on one of the XBee radios) when I discovered the following odd behaviour.
The following images show a wire connected to an output PIC pin (currently set LOW) and the other end to a small diode.  The DC- cable of the meter is connected to the circuit GND.  The first image [image: NoVoltage] shows 0 volts on the pin side of the cable, which is what I would expect because the pin has been pulled LOW in the code.

However, this next image shows 2.7V on the unconnected side of the diode [image: VoltageShowing]

Can someone please explain what is creating this voltage, particularly when only one side of the diode is connected (effectively, to ground).

Responding to comment by @Justme.
The diode is a small signal diode (IN4148), not schottky or photovoltaic . Not affected by light.  Same behaviour exists when I swap in a small SMD (1N4148WS).
Circuit is powered by an 240V -> 12v LED light transformer, which is then dropped to 3.3V using a buck regulator (MP-K78L03-500R3).

Thanks for your insights.

Mike

Comment: OK, which diode type that is, a regular, zener, schottky, and what model? Is the board powered by floating supply with AC common mode? The diode is in a glass package; does the voltage change if you shine a flashlight on it, or cover it so no ambient light hits it?

Comment: Your multimeter wire picks up some RF noise and the diode rectifies this. Could be an Y capacitor effect from the LED light transformer.

Comment: @Jens maybe, but I was a bit surprised by the voltage reading....it just happens to be around 3.3V less 0.5V - the drop I would expect across a diode.  As for the light aspect, this also occurs when I use a black plastic diode, and not a clear one.  I also saw a similar reading when the diode was in situ in the circuit...that's why I removed it and tested it hanging in mid-air.

Comment: Did you try another GND connection? Like pick the Ground from somewhere else on the PCB?

Comment: Yes. I get the same reading from multiple GND points.

Comment: @Jens offers possibilities. An oscilloscope with 10M probe substituted for your multimeter would offer more info. You might try a 3.3V battery power source.

Comment: "The diode is a small signal diode (IN4148), not ... photovoltaic . Not affected by light." All semiconductor diodes are photovoltaic; the ones sold as such are just optimised for it. You have a diode in a glass case so it will respond to light. However I wouldn't expect to get 2.7 V off a diode that wasn't an LED. Perhaps you're picking up some voltage from the board? Try moving the black lead from the DMM to the other side of the diode and then shine a light on it.

Comment: Thanks to both @GrahamNye and glen_geek for your suggestions.  I have already kind of destroyed the previous circuit in order to reuse components so I can't try your suggestions - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have this model in mind as an explanation.

Your 12 V power supply contains an Y capacitor. Typical values are 470 pF to 1.5 nF.

Your DMM wire has a capacitance (C2) to earth, GND in the schematic.

The DMM has an input resistance (R1) of 10 MΩ typical.

The DMM has an input capacitance (C3). The value is unknown.

The simulation shows the rectifier effect. The DMM would integrate such a signal to a DC voltage display.
I have seen such artefacts very often when I work with a laptop, where GND is not connected to earth.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXMrB9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thankyou for providing this possible explanation.  In this case, I'm not convinced it applies to my scenario though.  I was experiencing a high signal on the diode when it was in circuit, and this was causing a pin high on the sender XBee, and a similar value on the receiving XBee - causing a light to be illuminated when it should have been off.  I've now rebuilt my PCB, paying more careful attention to the alignment and soldering of the components, and the issue is no longer occurring.  I am therefore going to close this post and attribute the cause of the issue to user error.